# sqlalchemy ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY) with selectable

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

while creating sqlalchemy `postgresql` `WIEW` representation based on [this](http://www.jeffwidman.com/blog/847/using-sqlalchemy-to-create-and-manage-postgresql-materialized-views/) tutorial I need to construct a `selectable`. It works well in general but due to it does not work with normal `query` and has to be done over `select`, I experience difficulty to construct `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY)` with selectable.

one of the things I have tried:

```
row = select([func.row_number().over(partition_by=Table.cals_id,                                  
order_by=desc(Table.parsing_timestamp))]).alias('row')

q = (select([Table.listing_id,
             Table.date,
             Table.price,
             row])
             .where(row ==1))
```

This translates into meaningless

```
SELECT table.listing_id, table.date, table.price, (SELECT row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY table.cals_id ORDER BY table.parsing_timestamp DESC) AS row 
 FROM table) AS row 
WHERE 0 = 1
```

How to construct the `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY)` with `sqlalchemy` `selectable`?

Comment: @Ilja Everilä, that is exactly right: Did you mean to either wrap the query with the window-function and select from it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the row number and the needed columns in the inner query and restrict in the enclosing query:

```
sq = select([
    Table.listing_id,
    Table.date,
    Table.price,
    func.row_number().over(
        partition_by=Table.cals_id,
        order_by=desc(Table.parsing_timestamp)).label('rn')]).alias()

q = select([sq.c.listing_id,
            sq.c.date,
            sq.c.price]).where(sq.c.rn == 1)
```

In the original attempt in

```
row == 1
```

`row` is an aliased subquery, not a scalar subquery, so it does not have a meaningful override for equality. It would be asking if a table equals one. Since it does not override equality to produce SQL, the expression is evaluated in Python and produces `False`. Passing the `Alias` object itself as a column seems to trip the SQLAlchemy query compiler in all kinds of interesting ways, so don't. Select columns *from* it.